# JavaFxPorts Native Webview

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-webengine, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

Is it possible for the Android WebView to be implemented in JavaFx rather than the native Webview window that is being currently used because the native window causes lightweight vs heavyweight issues. I have a MenuButton that does not display any of the MenuItems because they are all hidden behind the WebView.

[image: This image shows the menu being displayed normally on top of a regular node]

[image: This image shows the menu being hidden behind the android webview]

The first image shows the menu being displayed normally on top of a regular node. 
The second image shows the menu being hidden behind the android webview.

Comment: Can you post an screenshot of your problem? It is not clear from the description if it is a WebView issue.

Comment: Thanks for the pics. There is a known issue with the JavaFX WebView on Android, as it tries to stay on top of the other nodes

Comment: Is there any timetable on a fix for this? In certain instances, Gluon Alert dialogs are being completely hidden by the Webview as well which can causes quite a pain. This occurs on both iOs and android.